# SQL Server MERGE statement : how does it match the destination table

Tags: sql-server

I am running a SQL Server `MERGE` statement for a one time load of data.

When it executes the condition statement to check for a match, does it consider the destination table before you execute the merge statement? Or does it also consider the destination table during the execution of the merge statement after data has been inserted.

So let's say the destination table was empty, and the matched condition was false and it inserted a record. Then later during the same execution another record that matched the same conditions? Will it go into the update or go into the insert?

```
Merge into tblDest dest
using tblSource as src on dest.col11 = src.col1 and dest.col2 = src.col2

When Matched then
    --UPDATE

When Not Matched then
    --INSERT
```

I've tried executing this and my code keeps trying to insert a record, which causes me to have a duplicate key problem (but that is a totally different issue and question). I'm just trying to understand what is actually going on when I Merge.

Comment: Well is `col1` the key, `col1`+`col2`, or something else?

Comment: Also, obligatory: [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Honestly it's much safer/easier to use the tried and true `UPDATE / INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS` in a transaction. That's all this variation of MERGE does for you anyway, except you still need to add transaction / isolation semantics yourself.

Comment: col1 and col2 are the keys, but I'm more curious to know what state the destination table is in, when it runs.  It looks to run as one big transaction, so when I query the destination table as merge is running, no records exist, so that makes me wonder if the condition will match or not.

Comment: How are you querying the destination table? Using the same isolation level as the MERGE statement? What do you *expect* a different transaction to see *while* MERGE is running? And does it matter for a one time load of data?

Comment: The merge statement is meant to join on Primary Keys, between the source and target tables.  A PK is distinct, hence you would not 'encounter' the same PK twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The merge statement only evaluates the join condition once at the beginning of the statement.  If you have two rows in your source table that would with the same join condition and none in the destination to match, both rows will be inserted. It does not insert one, re-evaluate the join and update the other.